# Вводится текст, конец ввода F3. Расставить слова по убыванию количества букв

Tags: c#, строки, текст

Собственно проблема состоит в понимании , можете помочь советом или идеями в реализации программы?
Вроде бы понимаю , что вводится текст , конец f3 , а само решение... сложновато .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace laba
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры текст . Необходимо отсортировать слова в этом тексте по убыванию количества символов в них и вывести на экран результат .";
            foreach (var word in s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length))
                Console.WriteLine(word);}
        
        static void EnterWhileNotF1(StringBuilder text)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadKey();
            while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.F3)
            {
                text.Append(input.KeyChar);
                input = Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем сложность ? вроде вы все сделали, разбили строку на слова, отсортировали в порядке убывания

Comment: я не понимаю , ввод текста , конец ввода f3 , вывод слов в порядке убывания и зависит от кол-ва букв в слове .

Comment: мне кажется я не правильно сделал , по этому и прошу помощи

Comment: Серьезно, я вас не понимаю. Ваша программа: 1. Вводит текст, 2. завершает ввод по F3, 3. разбивает текст на слова и 4. Сортирует слова в порядке убывания длинны и выводит их, ну все так по условию ??? в чем именно проблема, в каком из пунктов вы сомневаетесь ?)

Comment: Ну немного подрефакторить, я бы сделал что бы EnterWhileNotF1 возвращал стринг, и зачем туда передавать стр.билдер, не нужно, пусть создается в самом методе. И возможно по условию лучше собрать снова строку через string.Join и вывести одной строкой. А так я не вижу проблем

Comment: я новичок в программирование , вторая моя программа , пока что не особо уверен в своих способностях и правильности размышлений . Как-то так )

Comment: Ну у вас вполне не плохо получается) но на будущее, вопросы следует конкретизировать и спрашивать именно то в чем есть проблема или сомнения, а не в целом  о всей программе